# Accidental chmod 777 on laravel files made the custom app throw forbidden error in shopify store admin

Tags: laravel, apache, server, shopify, shopify-app

The title says everything. It's a laravel setup running on apache. I have full root terminal access. Managed to wreck the permissions and now the app just shows the 'Forbidden' message for the /authenticate/token route.

Tried all different kinds of permission arrangements for directories and files. Confirmed ownership by apache and tried ownership by sudo user on selective files too. Disabled selinux as well

Don't remember how but something gave me a hint that the problem might have something to do with the session files in /storage/frameworks/sessions.

Weird bit, sometimes the app magically loads, but most times it doesn't.

Help?

**EDIT:** Made a mistake while checking details. The route for which the Forbidden message comes is "https://[domain]/?host=[...]&shop=[...]&token=[...]". The route I mentioned above is actually the referring URL.

**EDIT:**
`.htaccess` from `/public` folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Error Screen in Shopify Admin (Dev Store)
[image]

Laravel Error Log: Clean

Apache Error Log: "[evasive20:error] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/[laravel-folder]/public/, referrer [same path as the previous edit]"

**EDIT:** Apache server/vhost config:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80> //don't worry about this, after routing through ngrok's tunnel it comes out as https

    ServerAdmin [email]
    ServerName [url]

    DocumentRoot /var/www/contact-us/public

    <Directory /var/www/contact-us/public>
       Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi, check owner and if needed change it to owner of related account by chown command. Set all directories permission to 755 and files 644. Run php artisan config:cache after all.

Comment: I've tried most of it already. User as root, sudo user and www-data (Ubuntu server). Permissions and quite a few artisan commands too, didn't help.

Comment: Maybe apache rebuild helps.

Comment: Apache is working fine as far as I can tell. I didn't do anything to apache in any form anyway. Added the server config in the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you try this:

```bash
php artisan storage:link
```

And make sure that you have all of the folders in your
storage/framework:

- sessions
- views
- cache

Comment: Storage linked successfully. Folders exist. Made a mistake in the question, added an edit for the same. Still nothing new.

Comment: Can you please share your .htaccess and error message :)

Comment: Added an edit for everything I could find. Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: I do think that you might be missing this rule
~ Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes 

Other than that, please make sure that apache added to the user-group

Comment: It was already there in some form, but I added your version. No change. Weirdly, it did work on the first refresh after I restarted apache after updating the VH Config, but then back to the same on the next refresh. If you mean whether apache is in the access group + owner of the laravel files, then yes, that's already there.

Comment: Can you please share access.log and error.log when you facing this problem? 
Thank you